# "Unable to load config data from 'aws-parameterstore:'"

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm seeing exception below after creating a sample Spring-boot application with io.awspring.cloud plug-in:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'aws-parameterstore:'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:126)
...
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.amazonaws.asap.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/' or File.separator
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferencesForFile(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:138)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

I'm assuming I haven't included the right dependency that adds code to register "aws-parameterstore" with Spring as a valid config importer.

My Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>myproject</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=MyApp
spring.config.import=aws-parameterstore:
```

From what I can read at https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-parameter-store  I'm using the latest versions of Spring Boot and AWS, so I don't need to depend on any starters to get this behavior.

I did add spring-cloud-aws-messaging since I'll eventually be listening to an SQS queue soon.

Thanks.